# Time machine deletes old backups when still >2 TB of 3 TB are free

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, backup, macbook-pro

I get messages that my Time Machine backup volume is full and TM has deleted older backups. But my backup target disk is an external 3 TB HD and Finder reports that over 2 TB of it are free (only some 820 MB used)!

I am backing up the internal 1 TB SSD (850 GB in use) of my Mac Book Pro Retina to that volume. I have also reformatted the backup volume and started all over with a new Time Machine backup to that fresh and empty target. But the effect reappears after 3 to 4 days.

All my trials to find similar reports on Google failed. It seems that other users have less than 25% free on their backup target when they run into this message. The only similar question I could find was [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151136/why-is-time-machine-only-using-20-of-its-partition-allocation) but it was not answered.

I am currently running OS X Yosemite 10.10.1 and the backup HD is connected through USB 3.

Comment: What is the layout of your external? Is it partition to separate disks?

Comment: The external HD contains just one partition with the default file system Mac OS Extended Journaled (not case-sensitive) which occupies the full 3TB of the disk. I have also tested a case-sensitive formatting but the effects are identical.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible the snapshots being deleted are local snapshots (see http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202301) and not on the external? Local snapshots start getting deleted when free space your **internal** volume (not the **backup** volume) drops below 20%.